# Converting string to datetime with strptime in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I'm trying to convert a string to datetime with **dd/mm/YYYY** format, but the function "strptime" seems isn't working properly. The result format isn't in the same that i am specifying in the function.

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
print (today)
today = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
print (today)

today = datetime.strptime(today, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
print (today)
```

My **output** is this:

```
2022-08-26
26-08-2022 00:00:00
2022-08-26 00:00:00
```

it seems that after the **strftime** function, the format is right, but when i call the **strptime** function, its getting back to the previous format **"YY-mm-dd"**

Comment: after `strptime`, `today` is a `datetime` object - which has not intrinsic formatting. If you need formatting, use `strftime` again

Comment: You should probably read the documentation and note the object type returned by strptime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
today = datetime.strptime(today, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
print (today)
```

That part is creating a datetime object.
You can do:

```
print (today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

again in the final line

Answer (score 1):

> it seems that after the strftime function, the format is right, but when i call the strptime function, its getting back to the previous format "YY-mm-dd"

That is because `print(today)` determines the format since you didn't specify one. As other's pointed out, `today` is a `datetime` object. When you `print()` a datetime object, python will choose a format for you, I assume based on your system's locale settings.

One concept to understand here is the difference between a value and the representation of that value as a string. This is what formatting a datetime is for.

I suggest you don't worry about the output here too much. As long as your explicit format with `strftime()` gives you the correct representation, then you are good. This formatting should only be used for output. Otherwise, store datetimes and datetime objects in your variables.